# libimobildevice on windows: ./autogen.sh not working

Tags: ios, windows, mingw, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to install libimobiledevice, (from https://www.libimobiledevice.org/,) on my windows PC so that I can run iPhone emulators and commands when I'm making projects, but I'm having trouble figuring out what else do I need in order to install and configure libimobiledevice. 
So far following the instructions, I've tried command:

```
     ./autogen.sh
```

and

```
     ./autogen.sh make sudo make install
```

These are the errors I get:

```
 ./autogen.sh: line 13: libtoolize: command not found
 ./autogen.sh: line 15: aclocal: command not found
 ./autogen.sh: line 16: autoheader: command not found
 ./autogen.sh: line 17: automake: command not found
 ./autogen.sh: line 18: autoconf: command not found
 ./autogen.sh: line 23: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

While investigating more on I installed MinGW (Basic setup packeages,) I've cloned libplist, ideviceinstaller, libideviceactivation, libusbmuxd, (I couldn't find libzip.) Still no where closer for getting this set up. Are there still some other prerequisites I need to check first before getting this point?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run iOS emulators on your Windows PC with libimobiledevice. That's not what libimobiledevice does. libimobiledevice provides APIs and tools for *interacting* with iOS devices, but not for *emulating* them.

If you want to get libimobiledevice running on your Windows PC, you may want to have a look at [libimobiledevice-win32](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/), which is a port of libimobiledevice to Windows which I maintain.

It allows you to compile libplist, libusbmuxd, libimobiledevice and friends on for Windows using Visual Studio.

You can find precompiled binaries of libimobiledevice here: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/qmfrederik/imobiledevice-net/build/artifacts